# CodeIgniter: How can I retain values after an invalid form submission?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, session

I've Googled and there are many ways of doing this in PHP itself, JavaScript/ jQuery/ AJAX and CodeIgniter session data/ flash data.

But I prefer to have do this within PHP. My form is very large and contains different elements like text inputs, dropdowns, radios, etc. However I tried the following on my inputs in the View (MVC).

Example:

```
< input type="radio" name "gender" value="Male" <?php echo ($gender == 'Male')? 'checked': ''; ? />
< input type="radio" name "gender" value="Female" <?php echo ($gender == 'Female')? 'checked': ''; ? />
```

This gives an error on page load, obviously because the $gender variable is not defined. I can fix this issue in Controller but it will be a huge process and fragment the code. Are there any alternative ways? Examples are welcome!

Comment: you can get rid of the error by doing (isset($gender)&&$gender=='Male')) ? etc

Comment: I have no idea why [___Man behind NSA leaks___](http://edition.cnn.com/2013/06/10/politics/edward-snowden-profile) wants to learn PHP

Comment: because php is so leaky

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#repopulatingform

Comment: @allen213 Thank you so much, just what I needed!. Please add it as an answer.

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Because I have to find a job in Ecuador now. LOL

Comment: @Dagon +1 for the comment! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of the error by doing

`(isset($gender)&&$gender=='Male'))`

Also read http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#re-populating-the-form

Answer (score 16):

codeigniter has set_value you just type your input name inside like example blow.
if the validation false it just retain the values you entered before.
example:

```
 <input type='text' name='last_name' id='last_name' value="<?=set_value('last_name')?>" />
```

and complete documentation is here.

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/

Answer (score 1):

add the post data to your view data
warning: this is a dirty and lazy way to do it according to your problem and your code:

example:

on the controller where you submit it:

```
function submit(){
 $data->post = $this->input->post();
 $this->load->view('view', $data);
}
```

on the view add this:

```
extract($post);
```

Comment: Thanks. But there's even more lazy way to do this as 'allen213' pointed above. That is CodeIgniter's: set_value(), set_select(), set_checkbox(), set_radio() functions. Otherwise, it will be pointless using a framework, right? :)